# I am running this query in postgres saying error 'operator does not exist: interval + double precision'

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, intervals

I am using this query

```
 SELECT
    (date_trunc('hour', b.pub_ts) - DATE '1970-01-01')* 24 * 60 * 60 +
        EXTRACT(SECOND FROM b.pub_ts),
    date_trunc('hour', b.pub_ts)
from tablename b
limit 10;
```

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: interval + double precision
LINE 1: ...ur', b.pub_ts) - DATE '1970-01-01')* 24 * 60 * 60 +  EXTRACT... 
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

After @Vao said i try the output is

[image]

the actual output should be

[image]

Because then i have to apply round on the decimal but it is coming in interval.

Like this

```
round (((date_trunc('hour', b.pub_ts) - DATE '1970-01-01')* 24 * 60 * 60) + 
               concat(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM b.pub_ts),' seconds')::interval,3)
```

Comment: btw, try running ```select EXTRACT(epoch FROM b.pub_ts)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
    + EXTRACT(SECOND FROM b.pub_ts),
```

try

```
    +concat(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM b.pub_ts),' seconds')::interval,
```

The idea behind is that seconds is the only part of interval (or timestamp) that can have decimals, so you need to explicitely define you add seconds with decimals - then it should accept it

Comment: That worked but I have edited the question the output i want .

Comment: this does not regard to your original topic. please create a different post wth different topic.

Comment: ok . Thanks. I will edit my question too. And marks as you answer was correct as per previous post.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to question

```
> round((extract(epoch from ((date_trunc('hour', b.pub_ts) - 
         DATE '1970-01-01')* 24 * 60 * 60)) + 
         EXTRACT(SECOND FROM b.pub_ts))::numeric,3)
```

AND also if you want day to be extracted instead of eposh

```
(round((extract(DAY from((date_trunc('hour', b.pub_ts)
 - DATE '1970-01-01')* 24 * 60 * 60)) + 
   EXTRACT(SECOND FROM b.pub_ts))::numeric,3) *1000 / 1000)
```

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/3FCF7C40.2040505%40klaster.net